# Is there a method to change iOS static framework to dynamic framework by script?

Tags: ios, frameworks

In our program, we will provide ipa to our customer. They will build some frameworks and inject to ipa. After resign, the ipa will work. But in some case, we need to use the same pod such as AFN. If
some global singletons in this Pod, the application will crash in some case. So is there any method to change iOS static framework to dynamic framework by script?

I read this blog:https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/convert_static_to_dynamic.html. But I can't find out all dynamic libraries which the target dynamic framework need from system. Is there any method to solve the problem?